# get function call stack from exception

Tags: python-3.x

When a python function fails, we get a traceback listing filenames, lines, and function calls.

Is there anyway, within an `except` block, to pull out *only* these function names? I would just like a list of the successive calls that lead to the failure.

I have looked at the `traceback` library and have run `dir()` on my exception, but I don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

I took one last look at the `traceback` documentation and figured it out.

First, use `traceback.extract_tb()` to get the `StackSummary`. This is a list of `FrameSummary` objects, which themselves are tuples whose third value is the function name. In full:

```
try:
  some_function()
except Exception as e:
  tb = traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__)
  for frame in tb:
    print(frame[2])
```

output will be something like

```
<module>
some_function
another_func_called_by_some_function
...
```